# Using a Fragment in Android 2.2

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments

I am using fragments for Android 2.2 (with backward compatibility) for the first time. I created a simple example to see how it works.

Here is the code snapshot.

Main Activity code:

```
public class FragmentExampleActivity extends  FragmentActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
           
    
    RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            changeView1();
        }
    });
    
    
    radioButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //changeView1();
        }
    });
}

protected void changeView1() {
    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new RadioActivity1();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    
      

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Main Activity Layout file (main_activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioButtonGroupLayout">
    
    <fragment android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.HelloWorldFragment" 
    android:id="@+id/generalView" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>


<RadioGroup android:id ="@+id/radioButtonGroupLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton1" android:text="Radio 1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:text="Radio 2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton3" android:text="Radio 3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Initial Fragment Class

```
public class HelloWorldFragment extends Fragment
{

public HelloWorldFragment() {
    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world_fragment_layout,null);
    return v;
}


}
```

Fragment which is called when radio button is clicked/checked

```
public class RadioActivity1 extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_activity_one_layout,null);
        return v;
    
}
}
```

layout for second fragment class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

snapshot of code to replace the fragment

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new RadioActivity1();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    
        transaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.generalView));

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
```

My problem is that the fragment is not getting replaced... I can see the HelloFragment Layout behind the second fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only remove/replace a fragment programmatically if it was added programmatically in the first place.

Remove the fragment node from main_activity.xml so that frameLayout has nothing in it. Then in your onCreate do something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, new HelloWorldFragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And then your replace code would look something like:

```
Fragment newFragment = new RadioActivity1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Also, you may need to change HelloWorldFragment to use an overload of LayoutInflater.inflate, add false as the last parameter, attachToRoot.